# API ограничения скорости

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Есть ли у Яндекс.Карт API ограничения скорости чтобы сторонним сервисом получить список ограничений скорости между точками? Вроде гугловского [https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=45.097403,38.979290|45.091597,38.977252&key=KEY](https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=45.097403,38.979290%7C45.091597,38.977252&key=KEY)

Answer (score 1):

Информации по дорожным знакам и скоростным ограничениям в API Яндекс.Карт нет.